# Getting Exception calling "Execute" with "1" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request." error

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage

```
 param
 (
 $table, 
 [string] $SubscriptionName, 
 [string] $SubscriptionGuid, 
 [string] $date, 
 [string] $ResourceQtyConsumed,
 [string] $ResourceRate,
 [string] $ExtendedCost
 )

 $entity = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DynamicTableEntity" #-ArgumentList $SubscriptionName,$SubscriptionGuid
 $entity.Properties.Add("subscription Name",$SubscriptionName)
 $entity.Properties.Add("subscriptionGuid",$SubscriptionGuid)
 $entity.Properties.Add("Date",$date)
 $entity.Properties.Add("resourceqtyconsumed",$ResourceQtyConsumed)
 $entity.Properties.Add("resourcerate",$ResourceRate)
 $entity.Properties.Add("extendedcost",$ExtendedCost)

 $result = $table.CloudTable.Execute([Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation]::Insert($entity))
```

I am getting the 400 bad request, I am trying to insert data from csv to the azure storage table.

Below is the error I am getting:

```
Exception calling "Execute" with "1" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."
At C:\kiran\powershell\Cost.ps1:76 char:2
+  $result = $table.CloudTable.Execute([Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage. ...
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageException
```

After research I got to know there is Rowkey and partition, but I am really not sure where to add those. I need the listed columns in my table but not partition or Row key.

While inserting data from azure storage table from powershell this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Storage tables [require a partition key and row key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-dotnet#add-an-entity-to-a-table). That is how the data structure is set up. If you want, you could give the same partition key for each entity, and use something like your `subscriptionGuid` as the row key.

Comment: Hi , Thank you for the response. can i get a sample code for this as my csv data doesnt have the partition and row keys, so i am declaring manually and appending to storage table, But still i am getting the error like Exception calling "ExecuteBatch" with "1" argument(s): "Element 0 in the batch returned an unexpected response code."
At C:\kiran\powershell\Cost.ps1:95 char:5
+     $table.CloudTable.ExecuteBatch($batchOperation)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException

Comment: @azuregeek: "can I get a sample code". Answerers here do sometimes create sample code, but it is advisable for new users to demonstrate they are not on the prowl for free work, and that they are very willing to make a substantial effort to fix their own problems. I recommend that whenever an answer is offered, it is used as a jumping-off point for new research, rather than something that can be typed verbatim. You are, after all, the only person who knows your exact use case.

Comment: Sure Thank you . I looked at the code and figured out what is going wrong.There was something wrong in the versions of the azurestorage module.